# Cannot display in UITextField inside UIView after success 200 from API

Tags: ios, swift

can you help me to resolve this problem

```
 WS.pay_bay_cb("some params") {
                          (response) in
          let  abc = response["response"] as? NSDictionary
           print(abc!["ref_code"] as? String) // i get this 12345 code that i want to display
           code_container.hidden = fasle  
           self.validation_code.text = abc!["ref_code"] as? String
     }
```

I want to display ref_code in UITextField inside UIView. 
The problem the view still hidden, anyone can explain to me how can do it to fix this problem and thanks.

Comment: Is your `self.validation_code` the UITextField?

Comment: yes @Benjamin Lowry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
WS.pay_bay_cb("some params") {
                      (response) in
      let  abc = response["response"] as? NSDictionary
       print(abc!["ref_code"] as? String) // i get this 12345 code that i want to display
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
       self.code_container.hidden = fasle  
       self.validation_code.text = abc!["ref_code"] as? String
})
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this safe way:

```
WS.pay_bay_cb("some params") {
    (response) in
    if let  abc = response["response"] as? [String:Any] {
        if let code  = abc["ref_code"] as? String {
            print("ref_code: ",code)
            self.code_container.hidden = false
            self.validation_code.text = code
        } else {
            print("ref_code data-type is not String")
        }
    } else {
        print("response data-type is not a Dictionary")
    }
}
```

Comment: let me know what's the output of `print`?

Comment: Non  @Mr.Bista is UITextField

Comment: Try `self.validation_code.hidden = false` below `self.code_container.hidden = false`.